# Laravel 5: issue with authorization and PDF generating

Tags: laravel, routes

My current result is Laravel's login window generated into PDF, instead of generating my offer into PDF. So, I need to fix this.

Here are my routes:

```
Route::get('/offers/view/{id}/{document?}', 
    [
        'middleware' => 'auth', 
        'uses' => 'OfferController@view'
    ]);

Route::get('/offers/pdf/{id}/{string?}', 'OfferController@pdf');
```

As you can see, I am securing first route with middleware auth. Logging into my app and going to this route I am seeing my offer, which is fine.

If you take a look at second route, this one is actually calling first route and generating its view into pdf. There are some params, which are not important for this issue. If you think differently, please let me know, I can explain further. If I secure second route, my issue becomes alive.

Here is my controller:

```
public function view($id, $document = '')
{
    $offer    = Offer::find($id);
    $services = Offer::find($id)->service;

    $total = new Total($offer->totalServices, $offer->discount, $offer->discountUnit, $offer->tax);
    $results = $total->calculate();

    ($document == 'pdf') ? $pdf = true : $pdf = false;

    return View::make('offerView', array(
        'offer'    => $offer,
        'services' => $services,
        'total'    => $results,
        'pdf'      => $pdf,
    ));
}

public function pdf($id, $string = '') 
{
    $offer = Offer::find($id);
    $url = URL::to('/offers/view/' . $id . '/pdf');
    ($string == 'stream') ? $stream = true : $stream = false;

    if ($stream) {
        return PDF::loadFile($url)
            ->callSettings()
            ->stream('Some_name_'. $offer->code .'.pdf');
    } 
    else {
        return PDF::loadFile($url)
            ->callSettings()
            ->download('Some_name_'. $offer->code .'.pdf');          
    }
}
```

How could I secure my route? It can not be public. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What exactly is your issue? You can just add the 'auth' middleware to your second route like the first one.

Comment: If I do that, then I am getting login window generated into PDF.

Comment: I see, the second route is currently made public, so anyone can access it and if they are not logged-in, they will get a pdf of the login page, right? But if the user is logged-in, they should see the correct page. I think you should put the second route under the `auth` middleware as well

Comment: No. If they are logged in, they get the login window into PDF. If they are not logged in, they get the proper PDF but this way route is public.